# C# round a Date to the 10th, 20th or 30th of a month

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a convenient way in DateTime to round a given date, in DateTime, to the nearest 10th, 20th or 30th of a month or do I have to calculate it myself? e.g. 12th of April becomes 20th, 3rd of April becomes 10th, etc.

Comment: What about 25 Feb, or 31 March?

Comment: Why does April 12th become 20th? I would assume that April 10th is nearer (2 days difference vs. 8 days difference).

Comment: You are asking for a convenient way, have you an inconvenient which you could show us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not built in function.

The code will depend on the desired behavior for days that are after the last ten of the month, for example 26th of February, or 31st of May.

Here's are 2 versions.

If you decide that 31st if May is 10th of June make sure to handle December where you have to change the year.

## Version 1

```
// This looses milliseconds
var day = d.Month == 2 
    ? (d.Day > 10 ? 20 : 10)
    : (d.Day > 20 ? 30 : (d.Day > 10 ? 20 : 10));

var d2 = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, day, d.Hour, d.Minute, d.Second, d.Kind);
```

Tests

```
21/02/2021 -> 20/02/2021
31/05/2021 -> 30/05/2021
1/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
2/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
3/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
4/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
5/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
6/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
7/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
8/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
9/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
10/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
11/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
12/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
13/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
14/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
15/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
16/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
17/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
18/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
19/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
20/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
21/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
22/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
23/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
24/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
25/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
26/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
27/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
28/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
29/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
30/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
```

## Version 2

```
var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month);
var dayCandidate = ((d.Day + 9) / 10) * 10;

var day = dayCandidate <= daysInMonth ? dayCandidate : ((daysInMonth / 10) * 10); 

// This looses milliseconds
var d2 = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, day, d.Hour, d.Minute, d.Second, d.Kind);
```

Selection of tests:

```
28/02/2021 -> 20/02/2021
31/05/2021 -> 30/05/2021
1/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
2/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
9/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
10/04/2021 -> 10/04/2021
11/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
19/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
20/04/2021 -> 20/04/2021
21/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
29/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
30/04/2021 -> 30/04/2021
```

Comment: Usually, April only has 30 days :)

Comment: @AakashM Upgraded

Comment: If you are rounding to a precision of 10 days, I don't think you are concerned with milliseconds or any time-of-day really. So just use midnight (00:00:00)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko which is handled by the next line.